# how can i add a textbox to twitter api script?

Tags: php, json, api, twitter

I have this twitter api script which pulls tweets from a specified user.

id like to know how i can change it, so that i can have a text box field instead of a fixed username.

here is the code

could i link the `else {$user  = "twitterusername";}` to a text box with submit button?

```
<?$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
if (isset($_GET['user']))  {$user = $_GET['user'];}  else {$user  = "twitterusername";}
if (isset($_GET['count'])) {$user = $_GET['count'];} else {$count = 20;}
$getfield = "?screen_name=$user&count=$count";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
foreach($string as $items)
    {
        echo "Tweet: ". $items['text']."<br />";
        echo "retweets: ". $items['retweet_count']."<br />";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here:

```
if (isset($_GET['user']))  {$user = $_GET['user'];}  else {$user  = "twitterusername";}
```

The username is only fixed if you are not passing a GET (aka. querystring) value for `user`.

If you visited the page with `?user=someOtherUsername` it would pull data back for that user.

So to have a form pass that value in from a text box, you could have something as simple as this in the same PHP file:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <input type="text" name="user" /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This is the same with your `count` value as well. You can control is by using another GET value with the name `count`.

Comment: thanks Turnerj that worked a treat, ive spent hours today trying to do this. thanks for explaing, it makes sense to me now :)

Comment: No problem, it can be easy to miss these things when you get a new code base or working with a programming language you might not be familiar with. Now you know your PHP code can do what you were wanting without modification, just that you needed to add a HTML form to pass the information up to it.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of this snipped it is going to use whatever user that is passed by $_GET. So if you want a form with text input to choose a new user, you will need to put one on the page submit it using a form with method="get".

Comment: We saw the same thing at the same time! +1 :)